# PrestaShop product Customization field override my js code

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.7

on PrestaShop 1.7 product page I try to edit Product Customization field, changing it title. For example I have code:

```
const text = document.querySelector('.card-title');
text.textContent = 'New text';
```

it works when I visit product page, fill customization field and save it, but when I add product to cart, default modal cart popups and after close it product customization field change to default view and all my js change aren't visible. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by one really helpful person from PrestaShop community, it is because prestashop reload only part of page I have to one more time run my code using

prestashop.on('updateProduct', myFunctionHere);